# Bot Emulator Framework Unable to resolve service

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm following the Azure EchoBot Tutorial for adding states and I was running into an issue running the bot in the Bot Framework Emulator. 
(The bot can connect. The EchoBot without any modifications will run fine)
This is what I added to the ConfigureServices Function in my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Create the Bot Framework Adapter.
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

        //// Create the User state
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

        //// Create the Conversation State
        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

        // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
        services.AddTransient<IBot, EchoBot>();
    }
```

This is what I added to EchoBot.cs

```
private readonly BotState _userState;
    private readonly BotState _conversationState;

    public EchoBot (ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
    {
        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _userState = userState;
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var conversationStateAccessors = _conversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationFlow>(nameof(ConversationFlow));
        var flow = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationFlow());
        var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>("User");
        var profile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}"), cancellationToken);
    }
```

The error I'm getting in the emulator is just POST 500 directline.conversationUpdate and this is a screenshot of the error I'm getting from the bot console:

[image: There appears to be dependency injection issues for resolving the services I added to Configure Services]

Thanks! If there's any clarification needed, I'll do my best to update it.

Answer (score 2):

[ConversationState(IStorage) Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.conversationstate.-ctor?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_ConversationState__ctor_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_IStorage_) requires a derived [IStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.istorage?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) but it appears based on the shown `ConfigureServices` that one was not registered with the `IServiceCollection`

This will cause an exception when trying to resolve the `ConversationState` as indicated by the exception message.

An example on line showed the following

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
    services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

    // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
    services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

    // Create the User state.
    services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

    // Create the Conversation state.
    services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

    // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
    services.AddTransient<IBot, StateManagementBot>();
}
```

Note the inclusion of a derived `IStorage` with the addition of a singleton `MemoryStorage`

```
// Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
```

Reference [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#create-conversation-and-user-state-objects)

Comment: Thanks! I got it now :)

Comment: @BrainMeme if this resolves the original issue [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356823)